# Octave 5.2.0 GUI: strcat (and other commands) suddenly not found (functioned before)

Tags: octave

I use Octave 5.2.0 in GUI.
After using Octave for 2 weeks I'm suddenly confronted with errors I didn't
have before with the same code.
Also today I suddenly received a message not finding the 'close' in this
code :

```
clear ; close all; clc;
```

> ```
> error: 'strcat' undefined near line 44 column 25
> error: called from
>     handleSto at line 44 column 24
>     testinvoer03 at line 69 column 1
> ```

```
>> EXEC_PATH
```

> ```
> ans =
> C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\mingw64\bin;C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\mingw64\notepad++;C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\mingw64\libexec\octave\5.2.0\site\exec\x86_64-w64-mingw32;C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\mingw64\libexec\octave\api-v53\site\exec\x86_64-w64-mingw32;C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\mingw64\libexec\octave\site\exec\x86_64-w64-mingw32;C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\mingw64\libexec\octave\5.2.0\exec\x86_64-w64-mingw32;C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\mingw64\bin
> ```

```
>> strcat("ddd" ,"fff")
```

> ```
> error: 'strcat' undefined near line 1 column 1
> ```

I found the `strcat` file `strcat.m` in
`C:\Octave\Octave-5.2.0\mingw64\share\octave\5.2.0\m\strings`.

Obviously the  not in the `exec_path`.
I also checked `path` which gave me a point only.
I have added `addpath("C:\\Octave\\Octave-5.2.0\\mingw64\\share\\octave\\5.2.0\\m")`
now the Octave command windows tells me:

> ```
> error: 'close' undefined near line 63 column 1
> error: called from
>     testinvoer03 at line 63 column 1
> ```

The code was:

```
%  &nd=1986-01-02               ??
%  &revision_date=2020-02-21&nd= ??
…
%
clear; 
close all; 
clc; 
land={'world'}; %{'world','us','jp'};
%
…
```

line number 63 was correct.
Anybody had this problem. Some advise please.

Comment: `exec_path` is irrelevant. What matters is `path`. Something happened to your installation that deleted the path. Did you consider re-installing Octave?

Comment: I have re installed the path and the path is '.' without any other. Then I added a second path with command addpath("C:\\Octave\\Octave-5.2.0\\mingw64\\share\\octave\\5.2.0\\m")  and this was accepted but didn't help. When I look in terminal there is a whole bunch of paths specified. Should I put them all in the GUI path?

Comment: I ment: "I have re-installed Octave and the path is  '.' " (installation was without any problem). In terminal version 'strcat' functions,  as is 'close'.

Comment: Look into each of the initialization files mentioned [here](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Startup-Files.html) to see if any of them resets the path.

Comment: I had accidently outcommented the word 'path' someware in the code and the path was each time reduced to '.'.  I had to use restoredefaultpath and correct the code. So this is SOLVED.

Comment: Great! Please write an answer below and then accept it. This way people will know you have a solution before they start reading the question an all the comments.